# How to explicitly skip checking part of the schema in zod

Tags: zod

I would like to understand if and how it is possible to skip validating parts of a schema in zod?

In the following example, I would like to validate the `foo` schema to make sure that the object contains a property `id` of type `number` and a property `data` of type `array` but (maybe cause there is a lot of data) I would like to prevent validating all the actual array entries in `data`.

```js
import {z} from 'zod';

const foo = z.object({
   id: z.number(),
   data: z.array(z.string()),
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This does the job:

```js
const dataItem = z.custom<DataItem>(); // type DataItem defined by you elsewhere
const foo = z.object({
       id: z.number(),
       data: z.array(dataItem),
    });
// { id: string; data: DataItem[] }
```

https://github.com/colinhacks/zod/discussions/1575